# how to pass a variable number of parameters inside a url

Tags: c#, url, windows-phone

hello I am trying to pass a variable number of parameters inside a HttpWebRequest url. My approach so far is this-

```
public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Anime>> RequestsAnime(string accessToken, int page = 0, params string[] optionals)  // All Anime
    {
        JsonWebClient client = new JsonWebClient();

        string baseUri = "https://anilist.co/api/browse/anime?access_token=" + accessToken;
        string completeUri = "";

        string parameters = "";

        if (optionals != null)
        {
            parameters = CollectionUtils.ToStringFromArray(optionals);
            completeUri = baseUri + parameters;
        }

        if (page != 0)
        {
            completeUri = baseUri + "&page=" + page;
        }
        HttpWebRequest reqForToken = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(completeUri);
        reqForToken.Method = "GET";
        var respToken = await client.DoRequestJsonAsync<ObservableCollection<Anime>>(reqForToken);

        return respToken;
    }
```

ToStringFromArray function

```
public static string ToStringFromArray(string[] arrayString)
    {
        string result = string.Join("", arrayString);
        return result;
    }
```

RequestsAnime Calling

```
string[] ds = new string[] { "&status", "=active", "&season","=fall" };
var nm = await Requests.CreateMultipleTasksAsync(ds);
```

CreateMultipleTaskAsync calling

```
 public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Anime>> CreateMultipleTasksAsync(int page=0 ,params string[] optionals)
    {
        Task<Auth> download1 = RequestsAuth();

        Auth length1 = await download1;

        Task<ObservableCollection<Anime>> download2 = RequestsAnime(download1.Result.Access_token,page, optionals);

        var animeList = await download2;

        return animeList;
    }
```

I know its a clumsy way. I need to know a better solution. My objectives are-

1. Pass variable amount of parameters inside the URL
2. Append the parameters with "&" and "="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you put all your query string parameters in a `Dictionary`:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "status", "active" },
    { "season", "fall" }
};
```

You can then call the following method generate a valid query string (notice the calls to `Uri.EscapeDataString`:

```
string CreateQueryString(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    return String.Join("&", parameters
        .Select(param => String.Format("{0}={1}", 
            Uri.EscapeDataString(param.Key), 
            Uri.EscapeDataString(param.Value)))
        .ToArray());
}
```

Just append the queryString to you `baseUri`:

```
completeUri = baseUri + "&" + CreateQueryString(parameters);
```